# Assetic dump producing a parse error after installing Bootstrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, less, assetic

I have just installed `leafo/lessphp` and `twitter/bootstrap` in my Symfony 2 project, but have come across a problem when doing an Assetic dump.

I have added both packages as below and done a `composer update`.

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "leafo/lessphp": "~0.4.0",
        "twitter/bootstrap": "*",
        "components/jquery": "dev-master"
    }
```

Then an Assetic dump (`php app/console assetic:dump --force`) produces this error:

```
Dumping all dev assets. Debug mode is on.

[Exception]   parse error: failed at `&:extend(.clearfix all);` /var/www/vhosts/dev/dev_ayrshireminis/app/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/less/mixins.l ess on line 643     

assetic:dump [--watch] [--force] [--period="..."] [write_to]
```

Do I need to update Less? Why is this error happening?

Comment: Not a problem Assetic but lessphp, who is unable to successfully compile the bootstrap > 3.0.0. See https://github.com/leafo/lessphp/issues/520 and https://github.com/leafo/lessphp/issues/432. 
I suggest you throw lessphp, and use less via node. Or better yet use sass with compass! ;-)

Comment: There's [less.php](http://lessphp.gpeasy.com/) compiler that supports current Bootstrap versions.

Comment: @seven-phases-max Thanks for that link. I have now updated my less parser to `less.php` and it works fine. Do you want to submit it as an answer and I will gladly accept it.

Comment: @Lughino Thank you for the advice. I have now updated my less parser!